# How to rename archives in Ubuntu's terminal?

Tags: command-line, rename, filename

I have the following files:

```
/home/wiki/15000_20000/xx00
/home/wiki/15000_20000/xx01
/home/wiki/15000_20000/xx02
...
/home/wiki/15000_20000/xx4686
```

How do I rename `xx00`, `xx01`, ..., `xx4686` to `152000`, `152001`, ..., `15204686`, that is, replace `xx` with `1520`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`mmv`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/mmv.1.html) you can do:

```bsh
mmv /home/wiki/15000_20000 'xx*' '1520#1'
```

`mmv` is not installed by default, but you can install it by running:

```
sudo apt install mmv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename a file with the `mv` command which is used to move and rename files ([see here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/umv.htm)).
In your case this would be for one file:

```
mv /home/wiki/15000_20000/xx00 /home/wiki/15000_20000/152000
```

According to the number of files you have to rename you should consider automating this process ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329505/rename-all-files-in-a-folder-with-a-prefix-in-a-single-command)).
This should do the trick:

```
for FILENAME in *; do mv $FILENAME Unix_${FILENAME#??}; done
```

You have to execute that command in the folder where the files you want to rename are located in.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename files with `mv`. So, use:
`mv [file you want to rename] [new name]`
See:

1. `mv --help`
2. `man mv`